# Python: Testing for approximate equality of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm trying to implement unit tests to test for the approximate equality of dictionaries. I'm aware unittest has AssertDictEqual and AssertAlmostEqual, but I need AssertDictEqual to test for approximate rather than precise values, and AssertAlmostEqual does not work for dictionaries. The dictionaries that will be tested may be nested several times so I want to avoid using a loop.

Could someone please suggest how I could overwrite the AssertDictEqual method to test for approximate equality of each value? (Assume values are floats that need to be accurate to the closest tenth)

Example: The following should pass a test where it's being tested against the same dictionary but with all integers.

```
{
'A': {'a': 1.01, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, 
'B': {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6},
'C': {'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9}
}
```

Comment: I would write my own function `AssertDictAlmostEqual` that calls `AssertAlmostEqual` for the respective `items()`.

Comment: @sarema Thank you for the quick response. Would that entail looping through each key (including nested keys) and applying AssertAlmostEqual to each value? If not, could you please elaborate on items()? I'm quite new to Python

Comment: If you have a dict `my_dict`, loop through it with `for key, value in my_dict.items():`, then in the body of the loop call `AssertAlmostEqual(value, other_dict[key])`.

Comment: `dict.items()` returns an iterator over the dict's key-value pairs.

Comment: @sarema Would that require a loop for every nested dictionary? I'm trying to minimize the time complexity of the solution and create a generic solution that applies to dictionaries with any amount of nesting

Comment: this is just one of many reasons why I prefer `pytest` as the Python testing framework, it already has things like this such as https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest-approx

Comment: @BenjaminLuo Yes it would. But that does not increase the time complexity. You are not trying to compare every item in one dict to every item in the second dict. With regards to time complexity, both dicts could be flat. You would just need to handle the case of nesting.

Comment: @sarema It seems the PyTest approx function does not work for nested dictionaries. The below is the error I got: 

TypeError: pytest.approx() does not support nested dictionaries: key='A' value={'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
  full mapping={'A': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
 'B': {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6},
 'C': {'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9}}